# Ruby On Rails - Simple_fields_for with nested_form, pass variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, nested-forms, simple-form, partial

Is it possible to pass variable when using nested form with Simple form?

Like

```
<%= simple_nested_form_for(@foo) do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :bar %>
  <%= f.link_to_add :bar do %>
    Add bar
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I have tried

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :bar, :locals => {:baz => 'baz'} %>
```

but it wont pick it up in the partial.

Partial: **_bar.html.erb**

```
<%= baz %>
```

[Simple Form Gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form)

[Nested Form Gem](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form)

Comment: I don't see any reference to a partial in your code. What partial are you trying to work with?

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the same thing and never did see an answer anywhere, so I'm posting an example of what worked for me:

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :answers do |answers| %>
   <%= render 'answer_fields',  { f: answers, question: @question }  %>
<% end %>
```

Also, if you want to access the current object from the collection being rendered within the partial, use f.object within the partial.

Answer (score 1):

To pass variables to partials, you use the `:locals` option:

```
<%= render partial: "my_awesome_partial", locals: {variable: 5, baz: 'baz'} %>
```

Comment: Just a typo, the problem is that I can't pass this with simple_fields_for, ordinary partial is working just fine...

Comment: Form helpers don't use partials. You specify partials yourself, where you want them in your view. I need to see what tutorial you're working from or more of your code to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm trying to access a nested forms parents attribute.
If you take a look at this: https://github.com/ryanb/complex-form-examples/tree/nested_form/app/views/surveys

You see that Ryan is adding new questions with his gem nested_form, I want to be able to send a variable to the partial with the question fields and also be able to send variable to the answers fields.